# como comparar las letras de un String que estan escritas de distintamente

Tags: java

hola lo que basicamente se es que podemos comparar un string con otro para ver que son iguales ejemplo

```
String n1 = "hola";
String n2 = "hola";
```

podriamos usar:

```
n1.equals(n2)
```

pero mi caso es que estoy haciendo un ejercicio de palabras trifelios las que al repetir varias veces forma otra ejemplo "monja" si tu dices rapido "monja" varias veces se escucharia "jamon" yo tengo un array palabraTrifelias en la que el usuario a introducido el numero de casos un caso es un par de palabras este par se almacena en cada posicion para ello a la cantidad de casos lo mutiplique por 2 para almacenar el par de palabras trifelias cabe mencionar que una palabra trifelio(a) no puede ser la misma palabra por ejemplo si la primera vez que el usuario ingresara digamos "paco" "paco" este en el output daria un NO ya que para que sea trifelia deberia ingresar "paco" "copa"

```
palabra[0] = "monja"
palabra[1] = "jamon"
```

lo que yo quisiera es comparar estas dos palabras pero se que con *.equals()* no podria por que los string son diferentes pero tienen las mismas letras entonces como comparo ambos caracteres para saber que ambos tienen la misma letra ya que en el output necesito devolver SI o No

por ejemplo eh avanzado solo esto: el for each que esta solo lo eh puesto para probar que se almacene en las posiciones que queria
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero segun el problema debe quedar algo asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tu necesitas que al comparar monja y jamon diga que si son palabras trifelios?

Comment: si pero con equals no lo puedo hacer asi que no se como hacerlo osea mi programa debe funcionar haci yo le pido al usuario la cantidad de palabras pares que quiere ingresar ejemplo

Comment: Se me ocurre que transformes los strings en arrays y vayas comparando la primera letra en el segundo array y si la encuentra sumarla a una variable digamos "coincidencias", luego la segunda letra con todo el segundo string y la tercera y así hasta terminar el primer string, si al final coincidencias es = a 5 en este caso, son palabras trifelios

Comment: `ingrese la cantidad de casos: ` 3                                                                  `monja jamon`  `copa paco`  `pavio viona`                                                                                                     `output:`                                                                                                         `SI`  `SI`  `NO`    **eh puesto dos espacios aqui en los comentarios entre cada valor para hacer referencia al salto de linea que deben llevar**

Comment: El mismo programa debe servir para los 3 casos o son independientes? Me refiero a si se van a usar sólo como ejemplos

Comment: Con un ciclo, la variable string tiene un metodo para acceder a la posicion de la letras ( CharAt() ) por tanto con un ciclo ya sea for o while que toma la primera letra y la busque en el otro string en las posiciones, con un bolean si la encuentra es true, si no es false y deberia salir. 
en caso de que sea true, si cumple, si arroja false no cumple.

Disculpa este es un caso [pavio]  == [viona] ??

Comment: osea el usuario ingresa los pares de palabras aproposito agrega "pavio" y "viona" en lugar de "navio" es por eso que arroja un No lo use como ejemplo

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, sólo cambia los strings según los casos y prueba si te sirve, me cuentas cómo te va por favor, estoy atento

Comment: eh editado para que puedan ver el ejercicio

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta.

Comment: En el caso de "lavese" y "besela" no tendrían que ser diferentes? Pero la salida dice si, ¿por qué?

Comment: Arroja que no cumple.

Comment: por que si lees dice que dado que la v y b son foneticamente iguales lo trateremos como si fuera solo b

Comment: Tendrias que hacer validaciones. ya lo aplique como dices pero faltan detalles modificare mi respuesta. prueba y me dices

Comment: leyendo me eh dejado pasar algo dice que no son trifelios si coloca la misma palabra eso quiere decir que si el usuario coloca "monja" "monja" no son trifelios asi tengan la misma letras creo que deberia comparar si sin iguales de no ser iguales recien se sabe que puede que sean trifelias o no si es que cumplen que los caracteres sean identicos y tengan la misma longitud

Comment: siento que me rendire con este ejercicio

Comment: Primero haces un equals y listo sabras si son diferentes, con un if lo sacas. PD: modifique mi respuesta

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76944/discussion-between-badbios-and-vladimir-joel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para lo que pides, que se puedan evaluar diferentes casos de una misma tirada, se haría lo siguiente:

Pongamos el siguiente caso:

```
    public String orderChars(String _str)
    {
        char[] arrStr = _str.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(arrStr);
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < arrStr.length; i++)
            str.append(arrStr[i]);

        return str.toString();
    }

    int casos = 4;
    String palabrasTrifelias[] = {"monja", "jamon", "copa" ,"paco" ,"pavio" ,"viona", "masa", "mesa"};

    Boolean resultado[] = new Boolean[casos];  //Aquí vamos a almacenar si están bien o no. Por defecto se inicializa todo a false, lo tenemos que pasar todo a true para la comparación que haremos luego.

    for(int i=0; i<casos; i++)
    {
        resultado[i] = true;
    }

    //Vamos mirando todas las palabras de 2 en 2
    for(int i=0; i< palabrasTrifelias.length; i=i+2)
    {
        String p1 = palabrasTrifelias[i];
        p1 = p1.replace("b", "v"); //Sustituimos las posibles b por v
        String p2 = palabrasTrifelias[i+1];
        p2 = p2.replace("b", "v");

        //Ahora ya podemos comparar las palabras de 2 en 2.
        //Primero tienen que medir lo mismo, sino ya no son iguales
        //Tampoco puede ser la misma palabra
        if(p1.length()==p2.length() && !p1.equals(p2))
        {
            p1 = orderChars(p1);  //Ordenamos los caracteres
            p2 = orderChars(p2);  //Ordenamos los caracteres

            for(int j = 0; j<p1.length(); j++)
            {
                if(p1.charAt(j)!=p2.charAt(j)){resultado[i/2]=false;} //Como están ordenados, comparamos 1 a 1 todos los caracteres
            }
        }else{
            resultado[i/2]=false;
        }
    }

//Ahora imprimimos los resultados
    System.out.println("Output: ");
    for(int i=0; i<casos; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(resultado[i]+ " ");
    }
```

Comment: Con este código comparas palabras de 2 en 2 viendo si son trifelias o no. Lo que no te va a servir es para comparar frases del tipo: "Dábale arroz a ..."

Comment: El ejercicio pide comparar trifelios ortográficos dejando de un lado tildes. Además de ello se deben considerar la b y v iguales. Además no te especifican qué palabras comparar por lo que el usuario podrá comparar las plabras que quiera y no las que decidas meter en el String de palabrasTrifelias. Por ello, esta respuesta no es correcta.

Comment: Ya he arreglado lo de las b y v. Las tildes no se deben introducir por teclado como dice el enunciado del problema y el listado lo he metido así para hacer las pruebas, si ves el código del usuario ya se ve que sabe recoger las palabras por teclado.

Comment: Me equivoqué en una cosilla, ya tienes +1.

Comment: gracias por el comentario y por el +1

Answer (score 1):

> Podrias hacerlo de esta manera tambien, como mencione en el comentario con charAt()

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner Entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Casos;

    System.out.print("Ingrese cantidad de casos: ");
    Casos = Entrada.nextInt();
    Casos = Casos*2;

    String PalabrasTrifelias[] = new String[Casos];

    for( int i = 0; i < PalabrasTrifelias.length; i++ ){
        PalabrasTrifelias[i] = Entrada.next();
        if( i % 2 == 0){
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    int nx = 0;
    for ( String Palabras:PalabrasTrifelias){
        System.out.printf(" %d : %s%n", nx, Palabras);
        nx++;
    }

    nx = 0;
    for ( String Palabras:PalabrasTrifelias){
        String n1 = Palabras;
        nx++;
        String n2 = Palabras;
        int contador = 0;
        // Verifico que tengan el mismo numero de carateres creo que deberia tener el mismo numero
        if( n1.length() == n2.length()){
            // Ciclo para recorrer el string n1
            for(int i = 0; i < n1.length(); i++){
                // Ciclo para recorrer string n2
                for (int j = 0; j < n2.length(); j++){
                    // condicinal para ir comparando
                    if( n1.charAt(i) == n2.charAt(j)){
                        contador++;
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
        if (contador == n1.length()){
            System.out.println("Si cumple"+ n1 + " con "+ n2);
        }else{
            System.out.println("No cumple"+ n1 + " con "+ n2);
        }
        nx++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Dentro del for que tienes donde muestras las palabras solo lo asignas a string n1 y n2 y listo lo demas queda igual
y avanzas el for de 2 en dos.

Answer (score 1):

Otra posible implementación:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    trifelio("monja", "jamon");
    trifelio("Paco", "copa");
    trifelio("carro", "roca");
    trifelio("lavese", "besela");
    trifelio("vota", "bota");
}

private static void trifelio(String str1, String str2) {
    System.out.println("esTrifelio(" + str1 + ", " + str2 + "): " + esTrifelio(str1, str2));
}

private static boolean esTrifelio(String str1, String str2) {
    if(str1 == str2) {
        return false;
    }

    str1 = str1.replace("v", "b").toLowerCase();
    str2 = str2.replace("v", "b").toLowerCase();

    if(str1.equals(str2)) {
        return false;
    }

    return str1.concat(str1).contains(str2) && str2.concat(str2).contains(str1);
}
```

La idea detras es que si 2 Strings A, B son trifelios, entonces se tiene que:

- AA contiene B
- BB contiene A

Comment: interesante , a mi se me habia ocurrido un metodo que ordene los string de a- z osea por ejemplo si el usuario introduce el par "cajon" "jonca"  como "cajon" y "jonca" estan guardados en dos posicion de un array  rescatar los string y en un metodo o si existe(no lo se) ordenar "cajon" de a-z en este caso el resultado ordenado de "cajon" seria "acjno" lo mismo con "jonca" ordendandolo seria "acjno" al tener dos string "acjno" "acjno" comparar con un equals para imprimir en la consola Verdadero y asi con ayuda de PabloSImon lo hicimos, me falta aprender mucho gracias por tu aporte amigo

Comment: @VladimirJoel lamentablemente ordenar la palabra por sus caracteres te daria que `cajon` y `acjno` sean trifelios

Comment: el programa funciona asi:

Comment: usuario ingrese cantidad de casos : 3 , entonces esos tres pares se almacenan en en un array de 6 posiciones las reglas son que la primera vez que se ingresan no pueden tener letras distintas ni repetirse la palabra supongamos que ingresa estos tres pares "monja" "jamon" "cajon" "jonka" "tiza" "tiza" a simple vista solo el primer par seria trifelio  y para poder imprimer en la consola se debe comprobar y con equals no se puede ya que todo seria falso por que asi como estan introducidas si lo comparamos con equals seria falso lo que yo decia crear un metodo que ordene los caracteres del string

Comment: de forma ascendente (a-z) con cual tendriamos string ordenados "ajmno" "ajmno" "acjno" "ajkno" "aitz" "aitz" (este par ultimo no es necesario evaluar otra vez ya que la primera vez que introduzco es falso por ser igual "tiza" "tiza")  entonces evaluariamos con equals si son iguales "ajmno" "ajmno" (true) , "acjno" "ajkno" (false) entonces en la salida seria VERDADERO FALSO FALSO

Comment: Y si las palabras ingresadas fueran  "cajon" y "janco" ? Si los ordenases serian "acjno" y "acjno" pero *no* son trifelios

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes plantear así siempre y cuando las dos palabras tengan el mismo length, claro que si una tiene más letras que la otra obviamente ya no serían palabras trifelios, lo que hice fue transformar las cadenas en arrays de caracteres y compara en este caso la primera posición de la primera palabra o sea la m de monja con cada una de las letras de la segunda palabra, si la encontraba sumaba uno a la variable de tipo entero llamada coincidencia, al final de recorrer cada posición de la primera palabra preguntas si lo que vale coincidencia es igual a la longitud de tu string, si es así, son palabras trifelios, sino, no son palabras trifelios

```
String palabra1 = "monja";
String palabra2 = "jamon";
int coincidencia = 0;

char[] Caracteres1 = palabra1.toCharArray();
char[] Caracteres2 = palabra2.toCharArray();

for (int x=0;x<Caracteres1.length;x++){
    for (int y=0;y<Caracteres2.length;y++){
      if(Caracteres1[x] == Caracteres2[y]){
          coincidencia++;
      }
    }
}

if(Caracteres1.length == coincidencia){
    System.out.println("SI");
}
else{
    System.out.println("NO");
}
```

Si te sirvió mi respuesta no olvides puntuarla.

Comment: pero como ves en la imagen ya tengo las entradas almacenadas en el array palabrasTrifelias como usaria entonces tu codigo ya que tengo que hacer comprobaciones de la cantidad de casos que dese el usuario me explico si el usuario quiere pone 5 casos cada casos son contiene dos palabras trifelias que estan almacenadas en un array palabrasTrifelias ahora como compruebo ?

Comment: Entonces ya no convertirías un string a charArray, sino la posición del array que es String a charArray y lo harías por parejas